# how to subtract an integer from the end of an alphanumeric string in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

i have column in dataframe which looks like this

Time
09:16
09:17
09:18

the values are string and I want to keep them string but i want to subtract 1 from each one of them such that the final result looks like this

Time
09:15
09:16
09:17

i have tried doing it iterative way but it takes too long   , is it possible to do it

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) :

```
df["NewTime"] = (df["Time"].str.replace(r"(\d+)$",
                                       lambda x: str(int(x.group(1))-1), regex=True))
```

Or in a datetime approach :

```
df["NewTime"] = (pd.to_datetime(df["Time"], format="%H:%M")
               - pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)).dt.strftime("%H:%M")
```

Update :

As very well pointed by @*[mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway)*, the replace can lead to a non expected behaviour/result :
​

```
print(df)

    Time NewTime (replace) NewTime (datetime)
0  09:00             09:-1              08:59
1  09:16             09:15              09:15
2  09:17             09:16              09:16
3  09:18             09:17              09:17
```

*DataFrame used :*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Time": ["09:00", "09:16", "09:17", "09:18"]})
```

Comment: The datetime approach is likely more robust. I guess `09:00` should be decremented to `08:59`, not `09:0-1` ;)

Comment: Hi mozway, TBH I underestimated the question when proposing `str.replace`. I updated my answer ;)